# Allocate memory for huge node tree dynamically

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc, calloc

I'm trying to make a function that allocates memory in blocks and than is able to assign a memory pointer for different structures linked together.

```
#define MEMSIZE 50*1024*1024*sizeof(char)
#include "globals.h"
void *AddBlock(void){
    memstart = (char*) calloc(1,MEMSIZE);
    if(memstart==NULL){
        printf("Hittade inte minne...:\n");
        getchar();
        throw 1;
    }
    memptr = memstart;
    return memstart;
}

void* GetSpace(size_t size){ //gör nytt block eller putta fram pekaren
                             //makes a new block or increases ptr

    void *tmp = NULL;//where the data should be stored
    if(( memptr+size+1 >= memstart+MEMSIZE) )
        tmp = AddBlock();
    else
    {
        tmp = memptr;
        memptr+=size;
    }
    return tmp;
}

void InitMem(void){ //init of memory globals
    AddBlock();
}
```

`memptr` and `memstart` are `extern char*`. `memstart` is start of block and `memptr` is where you are at. 
`InitMem` is run in `main` upon start.

globals .h

```
extern char *memstart;
extern char *memptr;
```

globals .cpp

```
char *memstart;
char *memptr;
```

E.g. 
    struct Node* TheNode = GetSpace(sizeof(struct Node));

But the code works really bad and gives a lot of glitches in the program.

Is there any common way to do this? When I allocate memory for each structure with malloc there are way to much overhead and that's a huge deal since the tree consists of millions of nodes.

Comment: What's your question? Memory allocation is a huge topic, and you haven't even defined your use case. For starters, do you need to free individual nodes? Do you need to handle allocations of different sizes? What's a typical allocation size? etc.

Comment: Yes they are of different sizes but doesn't have to be freed. The typical allocation size is about 16 - 88 size_t.

Comment: Your code looks reasonable to me.  The only thing you are not handling is alignment.

Comment: I added a padding so that memptr is always increased by a multiple of 8 size_t (64bit system). That should fix alignment right?

tmp = AddBlock();
int padding = size%8;
memptr+=size+padding;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This leg of code has a problem

```
if(( memptr+size+1 >= memstart+MEMSIZE) )
    tmp = AddBlock();
```

because it is not advancing memptr by size.